# Can someone identify this creature?

Tags: species-identification, entomology, limnology

I discovered a few of these while cleaning an outdoor fish pond north of Sacramemto California. What is this?[image][image]

Comment: Check the [species ID tag info](https://biology.stackexchange.com/tags/species-identification/info) for some ways you can improve your species ID question to help get a good answer.

Comment: mayfly nymph of ephemoptera species

Comment: Wonderful! Now I will go intimidate my friends with this knowledge. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

This is a Burrowing Mayfly nymph (order Ephemeroptera), more than likely of the family Ephemeridae.  The Bugguide site has very few photos of nymphs, but you'll find a near miss [here](https://bugguide.net/node/view/908342/bgpage) (the species shown is not Californian, but the related *Ephemera simulans* Walker, 1853 is; see [here](https://www.entm.purdue.edu/mayfly/na-species-list.php#FamilyEphemeridae) for other possibilities [you'll want to look for nymph photos of the species listed from "USA: SW"]).